# Rank of matrix with cosine entries

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the rank of the matrix $\def\rank{\operatorname{rank}} [\cos(i-j)]_{1 \le i,j \le n}$.

\begin{align}
\rank[\cos(i-j)] &= \rank[\cos i \cos j + \sin i \sin j] \\
&\le \rank[\cos i\cos j] + \rank[\sin i\sin j]
\end{align}
The latter two have rank 1 by row reduction. So the rank is at most 2. Take the first and last rows of the matrix, they are linearly independent since $$\cos(n-1)-\cos 1\cos n = 0 \implies \sin 1\sin n = 0$$ which is not possible because $n$ is an integer.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have an answer ready to post, but only after you edit the question to show your personal effort and for whatever context you need this in. Otherwise for now, I am voting to close this question.

Comment: I think the answer is rank = n (from smaller cases) but don't know what to use  to prove it

Comment: Please edit your post to include all of the scratch work or guess work you have done. As an aside I can tell you that $n$ is incorrect.

Comment: Ok I think I got it, am I right?

Comment: You have the right answer, see my solution now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the angle difference identity we have that

$$\cos(i-j) = \cos i \cos j + \sin i \sin j$$

So define the following two (linearly independent) vectors

$$\mathbf{c} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos 1 \\ \vdots \\ \cos n\end{bmatrix} \hspace{24 pt} \mathbf{s} = \begin{bmatrix} \sin 1 \\ \vdots \\ \sin n\end{bmatrix}$$

meaning your matrix can be factored as

$$A_{ij} = \cos(i-j) \implies \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{cc^T} + \mathbf{ss^T}$$

which makes the rank of the matrix $=\min(2,n)$